# Jquery Ajax call on IE8 is horribly Slow but very fast in IE9

Tags: jquery

I know many questions have been raised on JS & Jquery performance on IE. However, none helped me and hence I am forced to ask the question here. I am very new to JS & Jquery. However I am stuck with a problem. My application uses JS & Jquery heavily to render complex UI. The application is supposed to be running on IE (Various versions). The application uses a lot of ajax calls to fetch data and show on UI. The data is generally heavy many DB rows (1000s)...

Problem is, that the ajax calls work fine on IE9 but are terribly slow on IE8. I can not find the reason

Following is the way I call ajax function

```
ajaxRequestSync("admin/dashboard/alertLog.action", reqData, "logtable", renderAlertText);
```

Here is this function

```
function ajaxRequestSync(reqURL, reqData, id, completeFunction) {
alert(completeFunction);

$.ajax( {
    type : "POST",
    url : reqURL,
    data : reqData,
    dataType : "html",
    async : true,
    success : function(responseText) { 
        if(completeFunction == null) {
            renderText(id, responseText);
        }
        else {
            completeFunction(id, responseText);
        }
    },
    error : handleAjaxError
});
}

function renderText(id, msgText) {

if (id == "logtable") {
    var name = id+"Loading";
    hideDivById(name);
    showDivById(id);
}
//ask JQuery to clean text/html/events related to the contents of this node

cleanObject(id);
//ask JQuery to render HTML into this element
$("#" + id).html(msgText);
if(id == "alertdetail" && g_alertLinkStatus == true){
    unBlockSection(id);
    $(document).find('a.alert_link1').removeClass('alert_link1').addClass('alert_link');

}
}
```

Please let me know how can I make this work faster with IE8. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that it is the AJAX calls that are slow? It seems more like it would be your function after the AJAX call completes in 'success' that is slow. IE8 is likely to be slower at adding a lot of items to the DOM. Perhaps you can batch you function calls using setinterval, break up the results into a couple of hundred at a time.

Comment: I agree on this, and now I am also not sure that Ajax is the culprit, anyways only 1000 records are there in the data. This is as much as allowed. Can DOM loading take 3:15 mins for 1000 rows? IE9 takes 5-6 sec only and I feel that is slow too

Comment: Looking at it again, are you doing one big batched AJAX call or are you doing lots of smaller requests at the same time?

Comment: Actually doing one single batch.

Comment: yes msgText is a giant HTML string containing around 1000 rows with 10 columns.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments it is not the AJAX calls that are slow, but it is what you are doing with the result of the AJAX call that is slow.

IE8 is going to be slower than IE9 for large DOM manipulations, but 3+ minutes does seem a bit excessive (I have seen times like this in IE 6 & 7).

This [performance guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533020%28VS.85%29.aspx#Use_Fixed-Size_Tables) is still applicable to IE 8 and may help.

If the above doesn't help, I would start by trying to determine which part it the slowest. Try commenting out `$(document).find('a.alert_link1').removeClass('alert_link1').addClass('alert_link');` and see if that improves the speed by a noticable amount-IE 8 does not support `getElementsByClassName`, so using jQuery to search for elements of a class will be non-optimal on a large document.

Since `msgText` is a large HTML string (1000 rows by 10 columns) you may need to break this up (or page the results) i.e. your web service can return an array of rows and you could add these all at once or use `setInterval` to add them in batches and hopefully not block the UI. If you can break it up then you can use `find('a.alert_link1')` on the broken up parts and this should increase the speed since you can provide jQuery with a context and not search the entire document.

Comment: Dear row1, thanks for your inputs, I will try these suggestions and will update whatever the result may be. Just wanted to know that I appreciate your help a lot.